# How to load data into BigQuery from command line with WRITE_EMPTY flag?

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface

I'm loading CSV data into BigQuery from the command line. I would like to prevent the operation from occurring if the table exists already. I do not want to truncate the table if it exists, and I do not want to append to it.

It seems that [there is no command line option for this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data):

[image]

However, I feel like I might be missing something. Is this truly an option that is impossible to use from the command line interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right about CLI doesn't support WRITE_EMPTY mode now.

You may file a feature request to get it prioritized.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround for this can be by using `bq cp` as follow:

1. Upload your data to a side table, Truncate the data each upload

```
bq --location=US load --autodetect --source_format=CSV dataset.table ./dataRaw.csv
```

2. Copy the data to your target table using `bq cp` which support an overwrite flag

```
bq --location=US cp -n dataset.dataRaw dataset.tableNotToOverWrite
```

If the table exists you get the following error:

> Table 'project:dataset.table' already exists, skipping

Comment: WRITE_EMPTY is not the default for the CLI. For the CLI, as you can see in my screenshot and the link from my post, WRITE_APPEND is the default.

Comment: @carbocation You are correct, sorry for missing that. I edit my answer with a possible work around for you